# How to disable line breaks in footnote？

Tags: environments, footnotes, environment-variables, technical-environment, xfootnote

I clone the great project [stacks-project](https://github.com/stacks/stacks-project)

Because I don't like right-side-note (margin) in the original settings, I want to set it as a footnote

Since my level is not high enough to extract a minimal example, I tried to simplify my steps. Although the project is large, only 6 files are needed to reproduce the problem I met

```
-a----  categories.tex
-a----  my.bib
-a----  preamble.tex
-a----  stacks-project-book.cls
-a----  stacks-project.cls
-a----  chapters.tex
```

This is how I do it:

in the setting file `preamble.tex`, I change `Line 9` to

```
\newenvironment{reference}{[Ref]\footnote\bgroup}{\egroup}
```

then build one document like

```
pdflatex "categories.tex"
or
latexmk -pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode "categories.tex"
```

turned into a footnote indeed, but the unexpected line break occurred (p.7 in the pdf file)

[image]

How can I disable this line break?

Comment: Instead of pointing the community to a MASSIVE external project/link, can you extract only the relevant details into a minimal document that replicates your issue? Start [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/iTCb5zYm), for example, and update it until it replicates the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Werner Of course I'd want to do it, but I'm not good enough to simplify a minimal document out of such a huge project. My efforts simplified my steps and made it easy for anyone willing to help me to reproduce the problem I met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do

```
\newenvironment{reference}{[Ref]\footnote\bgroup}{\egroup}
```

It happens (accidentally) to sort-of work with `amsart.cls`, but doesn't compile with the standard `article.cls`. For situations like this you want to use [`environ`](https://ctan.org/pkg/environ) instead. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}  % works also for amsart

\usepackage[height=1in]{geometry} % just to generate reasonably sized previews for TeX.SE

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{reference}{[Ref]\footnote{\BODY}}

\begin{document}

Text
\begin{reference}
        Some more text
\end{reference}
\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]